# Generic union type inferred differently from equivalent direct union type

Tags: typescript, generics, type-inference, union-types

Consider the following:

```
type UnwrapNullable1 = Required<{ x?: (1 | undefined) }>["x"]
type UnwrapNullable<T> = Required<{ x?: T }>["x"]
type Test = UnwrapNullable<1 | undefined>
```

The type *UnwrapNullable1* is correctly inferred as `1`, but *Test*, which should be equivalent to *UnwrapNullable1*, is inferred as `1 | undefined`.

Is this a limitation of typescript or some kind of bug?

Comment: This is neat; haven't found an applicable GitHub issue yet, but for anyone else who gets there first, note that IntelliSense shows that `UnwrapNullable<T>` is reduced to just `T`.  So the compiler must eagerly resolve it, ignoring the `-?` modifier in the mapped type.

Comment: Maybe [microsoft/TypeScript#17521](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/17521) is related?

Comment: I'm thoroughly confused because I would have though that the "correct" value is `1 | undefined` rather than `1` but apparently I'm wrong. `{ x?: (1 | undefined) }` means that `x` can be set to `1 | undefined` or omitted completely, and I would think making it `Required` should mean that `x` must be set, but why can't it be set to `undefined`?  It looks like `x` can only be `1` in `Required<{ x?: (1 | undefined) }>`,  but it can be `1` or `undefined` in `Required<{ x: (1 | undefined) }>`.

Comment: @LindaPaiste it's mentioned briefly in the docs that [the `-?` modifier](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#improved-control-over-mapped-type-modifiers) which makes props required in a mapped type also strips `undefined` from the type of the output property.

Comment: @LindaPaiste also note that the `-?` modifier does this `undefined` stripping in [a weird way](https://tsplay.dev/rNdadm).

Comment: @jcalz just when I think I understand this stuff... 

Comment: @jcalz did you (or anyone here) file an issue for this bug? should I go on and raise an issue for this?

Comment: I haven’t filed an issue. It’s up to you whether you want to file an issue yourself. I do think it would be interesting to get an official word on this, for what it’s worth.

Comment: I have created an issue https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/45676